# How to correctly authorize into Mongo server using Scala?

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I have added authorization to my Mongo database and now I can't perform any queries whats so ever.

Every time I try I get:

> reactivemongo.core.commands.DefaultCommandError: BSONCommandError['command failed      because the 'ok' field is missing or equals 0'] with original doc {
>     ok: BSONDouble(0.0),
>     errmsg: BSONString(unauthorized)
>   }

And my Authorization bit seams to be alright but it is just not doing the job:

```
private val driver = new MongoDriver(actorSystem)
private val dbName = "myDatabase"
private val userName = "root"
private val password = "pass"
private val credentials = Seq(Authenticate(dbName, userName, password))
private val connection = driver.connection(List("111.111.111.11"), credentials)
//connection.authenticate(dbName, userName, password)
private val db = connection(dbName)
```

The user credentials were created 
Any ideas on what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `unauthorized` means not that I has not logged in it means that the user does not have [sufficient permissions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#readWrite) or Roles as they are grouped in Mongo.

Some tutorials about adding authorization have skipped that part er go I get to relearn the lesson of reading an official documentation of any resource again...
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.addUser/